# .Net reporting and database contols

Tags: controls, telerik, reporting, devexpress

I am looking for a reporting and database contols solution. This post is not a rate the control but what has your experience been when using it.

I had a look at Telerik, DevExpress, Syncfusion and a few others. I have downloaded a copy of each and tested each for a week or so. However these arent cheap when I make the investment I would like to base it on othera experience as well as my own feel for the tools.

I had read all the post on SO and many other sites. Many outdated so wanted to know more recent experiences.

DevExpress looks great and seems to be what im lookig for however from what ive read their controls are coded and very differet ways. WPF is apparently very bad. I could be wrong though and please correct if i habe been misinformed.

Everyone seem to be happy with Telerik.

I will probably be customising later on so source is important. Winforms will be used. But would like to migrate to WPF and/or ASP.Net later. This is client requirements.

thanks in advance

Comment: Everyone?....like who?...make no mistake...Telerik is "iffy"...while DevExpress is "jiffy"...look at the support forums, at the questions asked...that gives you all the clue you need...besides...why not download a trial and give it test run?

Comment: As I said in the post I have tried each one, but a trial doesnt go as far as someone who has been using it for a while. In terms of everyone... I did a google search and most post came up with very similar coclusions.

Answer (score 2):

You should list down your expectations from a third party suit. 
Also its better to compare individual components rather than the whole suit.

I have lot of experience with devexpress@winforms, but the learning curve is quite steep.

I don't like the layout controls. Rest of the controls are pretty slick. Reports and Charts are good.
Support is also quite good.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with DevExpress scheduler for WinForms right now, and I can say only praises for this component suite. Everything is accessible easily, customizations are very easy; but to be honest I still haven't done any major customization, so it could be possible that 95% cases are easy, but that 5% is impossible (not sure, don't have that much experience with DevExpress). I would just say that they are much better than Infragistics WinForms suite.

Also reporting suite (XtraReports) is well known as a very good solution.